# Symfony2 uglify CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, assets, assetic

I am trying to

> php app/console assetic:dump

to test my prod environnement.
My css file is generating but not my js file. I have this error message :

```
C:\wamp\www\projet>php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
Dumping all prod assets.
Debug mode is off.

09:48:02 [file+] C:/wamp/www/projet/app/../web/css/666.css



[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]
An error occurred while running:
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.EXE" "C:\wamp\www\projet\app\Resources\node_
modules\.bin\uglifycss" "C:\Users\GoeresAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\inp3AC2.tm
p"

Error Output:

C:\wamp\www\projet\app\Resources\node_modules\.bin\uglifycss:4
case `uname` in
^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token case
  at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:906:3
```

This is my javascript block in my layout :

```
{% block javascripts %}
  {# jQuery depuis le CDN de Google, ou fallback sur une copie locale #}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    {# Tous nos javascripts avec Assetic #}
  {% javascripts output='js/666.js' filter='?uglifyjs2' 
    'js/*.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
  {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

And my running css block :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  {% stylesheets output='css/666.css' filter='?uglifycss'
    'css/*.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset_url}}" type="text/css" />
  {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have this line in my app.php :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

My config.yml :

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ ]
filters:
    uglifyjs2:
        bin: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs
    uglifycss:
        bin: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/.bin/uglifycss
```

**EDIT :**

I edited my code to use uglify instead of YUI.
But it is worse than before because none of JS and CSS are running now in prod.

Comment: That *"exceeded the timeout"* message hints (to me) that the this is an Assetic specific option. In any case, the max execution time for the CLI should be unlimited.

Comment: So, the 60 seconds is defined in `Assetic\Util\ProcessBuilder`. It has a *setter* method for the `$timeout` property but I'm not sure how to set it via the console command.

Comment: I tryied to change manually the value of timeout in processbuilder and I edit my question with my results.

Comment: CLI and apache have separate php.ini files. Are you sure you edited the correct php.ini?

Comment: Though this doesn't specifically answer your question it may be worth noting that the YUI Compressor is going through a deprecation process. (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html). It is now recommended to use uglify for minification. (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/uglifyjs.html)

Comment: @ FuzzyTree : I edited the php/ini from wamp in php menu.

@ threeandme : I follow the instructions for uglifyjs for css and js, and I have the same proceedings.

Comment: @Deynis `php -i | find /i "Configuration File"` should display the location of the CLI php.ini

Comment: It is at 30sec. But the error said "Timeout of 60sec". I don't understand. 
And now, I haven't only this error but all the contain of my js files printed in the console.

Comment: PHP also has a "Wait for other processes" timout value. This one is typically at 60 seconds. Its called `max_input_time`

Comment: I don't have any time problem now, I have a different error message base on uglify files.

Answer (score 3):

You configured the wrong paths for the `uglifyjs` and `uglifycss` scripts. Assetic executes these scripts via the executable of Node.js - but you configured the paths to the binary versions of `uglifyjs` and `uglifycss` instead (which are standalone).

The correct configuration would be:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ ]
filters:
    uglifyjs2:
        bin: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
    uglifycss:
        bin: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/uglifycss/uglifycss
```

The correct path to the `uglifyjs` script depends on your installed version.